# Spring MVC controller is not Called

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am first time writing sping application program and its not working

This is my Controller Class

```
package com.programcreek.helloworld.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    public HelloWorldController()
    {
        System.out.println("This is my constructor");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
     public String showMessage(Model model) {
        System.out.println("shiva");
    //  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("helloworld");

        return "this is it";
    }
}
```

Index.jsp

```
     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

 <html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> <title>Spring 4 MVC - HelloWorld Index Page</title> 
</head>
 <body> 
<center>
 <h2>Hello World</h2> 
<h3>
 <a href="home">Click Here</a> 
</h3> </center> 
</body> 
</html>
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

This is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.programcreek.helloworld.controller"></context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.programcreek</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>HelloWorld Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>HelloWorld</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am not getting any error log on my console

Thank you

Comment: And how do you access your page ?

Comment: I normally do the following 
Run as -> maven Install -> Run on Server

Then after that I get the landing page correctly , on my landing page(index.jsp) their is click here link when I click that I get 404.
Actually the controller is not getting called , because I am not able to see the System.out.println out put on my console which I have written in my controller class constructor.

Comment: Yes you need to get the mapping correct to access the controller, show us the code you have in your `index.jsp`

Comment: This is my Index.jsp


<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 

pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring 4 MVC - HelloWorld Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <center>
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <h3>
   <a href="home">Click Here</a>
  </h3>
 </center>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

You have added the `suffix` in your `web.xml` , but missed to utilize in your jsp , change your link url to

```
<a href="home.jsp">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. the reason why `System.out.println()` in the constructor is not invoked is that Spring uses lazy initializing strategy as default unless you declared otherwise in Spring context xml. The `controller` will not be initialized until it is accessed the 1st time.
2. you can type "your-application-context/home" in your browser, so this will try to invoke `HelloWorldController#showMessage()`. At that time, your console should print the message declared in the constructor. However, later the HTTP request probably would end up as an error. When you declared the view resolver, Spring will try to find a match jsp file in "declared-prefix/[the return string from the mothod].jsp. In your case, it might end up with no such file found, therefore a 404 or 500 server error.

I think what you are trying to do is to just execute the `showMessage()` method. What you might consider is to add an annotation above this method like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
@ResponseBody
 public String showMessage(Model model) {
    System.out.println("shiva");
//  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("helloworld");

    return "this is it";
}
```

The `ResponseBody` will tell spring to simply return the string as the response body.